# SQL retrieve distinct rows by the version number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying creating a saved view in MSSQL that is returning a list of proposals that were accepted.  The issue I'm having is if the proposal has more than one version it's returning all of the rows as accepted even though it's really only the latest version thats valid.

The Quote ID is different for each proposal record, but the quote number and the name is the same.  The way to determine which Quote ID record we would like to return would be the proposal with the latest version number.  Only a few quotes have version numbers and most are unique to begin with.

I don't know if I can do this by grouping data because there are many fields I would like to gather (other than ones listed below) that have mostly text within them.

Here is an example of the data format I'm referring to

```
Quote ID   |   Quote Number   |   Quote Name     | Version |

i3hfkdkj   |   101   |   John Smith Residence    |    1    |
fheifjdh   |   102   |   Big Apple Food Service  |    1    |
kdjfnf98   |   103   |   Starbucks Coffee        |    1    |
3498fhkd   |   101   |   John Smith Residence    |    2    |
jfh3bfi3   |   104   |   Susan Jane Apartment    |    1    |
9834jfkd   |   101   |   John Smith Residence    |    3    |
```

Ideally I would like the query to ONLY return the following rows

```
fheifjdh   |   102   |   Big Apple Food Service  |    1    |
kdjfnf98   |   103   |   Starbucks Coffee        |    1    |
jfh3bfi3   |   104   |   Susan Jane Apartment    |    1    |
9834jfkd   |   101   |   John Smith Residence    |    3    |
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help

Dan

Here is the syntax for my current saved view which is working properly with the exception of whats listed above.

```
SELECT
dbo.Quote_Main.quote_readable_id,
dbo.Quote_Main.quote_name,
dbo.Quote_Main.account_name,
dbo.Quote_Main.contact_name,
dbo.Quote_Main.quote_status,
dbo.Quote_Main.delivered_date,
dbo.Quote_Customers.first_name,
dbo.Quote_Customers.last_name,
dbo.Quote_Customers.customer_source,
dbo.Quote_Main.idCRM_opportunity,
dbo.Quote_Main.idQuote_Main,
dbo.Quote_Items.item_notes_html AS QuoteScope,
dbo.Quote_Items.item_notes,
dbo.Quote_Main.version

FROM
dbo.Quote_Items
LEFT JOIN dbo.Quote_Main ON dbo.Quote_Items.idQuote_Main = dbo.Quote_Main.idQuote_Main
LEFT JOIN dbo.Quote_Customers ON dbo.Quote_Main.idQuote_Main = dbo.Quote_Customers.idQuote_Main
WHERE
dbo.Quote_Items.long_description = 'Proposal Scope' AND
dbo.Quote_Main.quote_status = 'Won' AND
dbo.Quote_Customers.usage_type = 'Quote To'
```

Comment: Look at `GROUP BY` clause and `MIN()` function.

Comment: microsoft sql server.  I added more information as well :)

Answer (score 2):

One approach is with `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from proposals p
where not exists (select 1
                  from proposals p2
                  where p2.QuoteNumber = p.QuoteNumber and p2.version > p.version
                 );
```

You don't specify what database you are using and this should work in basically all databases for a view.

EDIT:

Just use a CTE:

```
with proposals as (
      <your query here>
     )
select p.*
from proposals p
where not exists (select 1
                  from proposals p2
                  where p2.QuoteNumber = p.QuoteNumber and p2.version > p.version
                 );
```

I would run this first to see if it has reasonable performance.  If not, there is probably scope for optimization.

Comment: I added my code to the posting.  Can you please show me the syntax you are referring to with my code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server, you can use [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
select * 
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by [Quote Number] order by Version desc) [rn]
    from Quotes
) x
where x.rn=1
```

This assigns a number to each row - the number is ordered by version (descending), and resets for each quote number. The result of the subquery looks like this:

```
Quote ID   | Quote#  |   Quote Name              | Version |  rn   |

i3hfkdkj   |   101   |   John Smith Residence    |    1    |   3   |
fheifjdh   |   102   |   Big Apple Food Service  |    1    |   1   |
kdjfnf98   |   103   |   Starbucks Coffee        |    1    |   1   |
3498fhkd   |   101   |   John Smith Residence    |    2    |   2   |
jfh3bfi3   |   104   |   Susan Jane Apartment    |    1    |   1   |
9834jfkd   |   101   |   John Smith Residence    |    3    |   1   |
```

Then we simply filter on `rn=1`.

The subquery is necessary because `row_number()` cannot be used in a `where` clause directly.

Comment: or any dbms that supports ROW_NUMBER() such as Oracle

Comment: Indeed. I'm not sure the syntax is exactly the same though.

Comment: yes it is, except you would not use [] to denote fields, conveniently you left out the 'as' in from of x which Ora would not like either

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  Can you please take a look at the code I posted and let me know how I can apply what you wrote to my code?

Comment: @Dan Levine do you mind if I add a suggested re-write in my answer? But I will make the assumption it is quote_items that needs row_number(). Also those left joins aren't working :( you may as well use inner joins in that query

Comment: @Used_By_Already please post your own answer - don't rewrite mine.

Comment: @Blorgbeard sincere apologies, I just reacted to the request above without looking, believe it or not it hadn't occurred to me it wasn't my answer. `My bad`; still learning this ui & darn as I didn't keep the query.

Comment: @Used_By_Already no problem. BTW, you can see the edit history by clicking on the "edited 1 hour ago" link - and there you can find your query.

Comment: @Blorgbeard thank you, I did manage to retrieve from my editor's endless undo :). sorry for the inconvenience caused, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

At request this is a worked-up example applied to an added query in the answer.

The overall structure of this query has changed from the original by moving the table dbo.Quote_Main up in precedence and conversely dbo.Quote_Items downward.

```
SELECT
      QM.quote_readable_id
    , QM.quote_name
    , QM.account_name
    , QM.contact_name
    , QM.quote_status
    , QM.delivered_date
    , QC.first_name
    , QC.last_name
    , QC.customer_source
    , QM.idCRM_opportunity
    , QM.idQuote_Main
    , QI.item_notes_html AS QuoteScope
    , QI.item_notes
    , QM.version

FROM dbo.Quote_Main QM
      INNER JOIN dbo.Quote_Customers
                  ON QM.idQuote_Main = QC.idQuote_Main
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                        SELECT
                              idQuote_Main
                            , item_notes_html
                            , item_notes
-- note 1
                            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idQuote_Main
                                                 ORDER BY qi_version DESC) AS RN
-- note 2
                        WHERE long_description = 'Proposal Scope'
                        FROM dbo.Quote_Items
                      ) QI
                        ON QM.idQuote_Main = QI.idQuote_Main
                              AND QI.RN = 1
WHERE QM.quote_status = 'Won'
    AND QC.usage_type = 'Quote To'
;
```

1. this field isn't specified so `qi_version` is guessed, use correct field
2. might be a where clause condition, or might be used in the subsequent join condition, the impact of placement will alter the results so please test both to choose most appropriate option.

Answer (score -1):

just to pile on a bit

```
select quoteid,quotenum,quotename,ver from quotes q
where quotenum||ver = (select max(quotenum||ver) from quotes q2
                        where q.quotenum=q2.quotenum)
```